# Get XML node values using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I need help with constructing a query that will give me all of the values for a particular XML node. I have a table that has information stored in it in xml. The xml data is like below:

```
<category>
   <text>Laser Printers</text>
   <title id="1">
      <text>HP OfficeJet Pro 8610</text>
   </text>
   <title id="2">
      <text>HP OfficeJet Pro 8700</text>
   </text>
   <title id="3">
      <text>Canon PIXMA MX 922</text>
   </text>       
</category>
```

I'm only able to get the value from the first node for each row in the table using this query.

```
SELECT it.contents.value('(category/title/text)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') as Printer
FROM inventory i
INNER JOIN store_products p ON i.inventoryId = p.inventoryId
INNER JOIN items it ON p.itemId = it.itemId
```

So my result is:

```
Printer
HP OfficeJet Pro 8610
```

What I need is the following:

```
Printer
HP OfficeJet Pro 8610, HP OfficeJet Pro 8700, Canon PIXMA MX 922
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Your XML is invalid - the `<title>` nodes should each have an `</title>` endnode - not a `</text>` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CROSS APPLY` and the `.nodes()` XQuery function - something like this:

```
SELECT 
    XC.value('(text)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS Printer
FROM 
    inventory i
INNER JOIN 
    store_products p ON i.inventoryId = p.inventoryId
INNER JOIN 
    items it ON p.itemId = it.itemId
CROSS APPLY
    it.contents.nodes('/category/title') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: Thank you!! One more quick question, I have another column called 'Store #' that is included in the query as the first column. Sorry I forgot to add that. How can I have the results grouped by that column?

Comment: @user721126: a grouping only makes sense if you have columns in your select list that have **aggregates** applied to them - `COUNT`, `MIN/MAX`, `AVG` etc. Maybe you just mean *order by* (sorting)? Sure, that's not problem - just add `ORDER BY StoreNumber` at the end